# iOS uiwebview goBack history control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am loading a "webpage1" on an uiwebview and saving its first request on an instance variable "webviewHistory". Then, I must reuse that webview to load another page, "webpage2" (saved its first request to "webviewHistory" too), and history should start now from this request. Problem is if I execute goBack (button IBAction) from "webpage2", I can keep going back to "webpage1" history and following. 
If I check request and compare with initial saved, works! but not with redirections, for example, if I trigger request to www.youtube.com, request is redirectioned to m.youtube.com and first one is not saved as navigation history! how to solve it?

```
if (![webViewSocial.request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:self.webviewHistory]){
    [webViewSocial goBack];
    }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

UIWebviews have instance methods that allow you to go backwards and forwards with the history, without you having to track the last request. Is there a particular reason you are saving the last request specifically?

Sample code:

```
if ([webView canGoBack]) {
    [webView goBack];
}
```

Here is a project that is a simple uiwebview browser if you want to play with it:
https://github.com/msencenb/UIWebView-Example

Comment: I am already using this methods but I need to enable or disable goBack action depending if request is older that first loaded page!

Comment: Ok. I think you should wait for redirection to happen on first page (so you get the correct first page loaded) using uiwebview delegate method: webViewDidFinishLoad:   then save to your instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

for swift 3 version of Msencenb answer:

```
if webView.canGoBack {
    webView.goBack()
}
```