# How to use UIButton to make UIWebView go back

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView and i want when users go to a link in it they can go back hereis my webview code

```
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 430)];   // x is width,y is hght


    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://livewiretech.co.nf/   NSURL *url =  [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

And i have a UIButton and the code for it is

```
    -(void) backButtonPressed {
    //Back code here
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872498/ios-uiwebview-goback-history-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should get you going

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView * webView;

....

webView = [[UIWebView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 430)];   // x is width,y is hght

NSString *urlAddress = @"http://livewiretech.co.nf/";
NSURL *url =  [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];


 -(void) backButtonPressed {
    if ([webView canGoBack]) {
        [webView goBack];
    }
 }
```

Comment: I get a lot of errors when i try to compile do you have email or kik where i can send u the screenshot?

Comment: Thans somuch i figured it out you need to tweak your answer though all places where webView are you need to put _webView

Comment: oops i should have added a line to synthesize.  no worries.  glad you figured it out! :)

Comment: Perhaps you should also add the @property goes in the header file begginers moght nt understand and because this is LITERALLY the only answer that works on stack overflow